# How to merge two array of objects in one big array

Tags: javascript, lodash

A want to merge two array of objects. The arrays are as follows :

```
let vehicle_data = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "make_text": "Peugeot",
    "model_text": "307",
    "color_text": "Bleu",
    "category_text": "CT",
    "vin": "654321",
    "autralis_id": 0
  }
]

let vehicle_slot_data = [
  {
    "vehicle_id": 1,
    "zone": "T",
    "side": "B",
    "col": 2,
    "handled": 0,
    "uploaded": 0
  },
  {
    "vehicle_id": 1,
    "zone": "A",
    "side": "E",
    "col": 1,
    "handled": 0,
    "uploaded": 0
  }
]
```

I want to merge these two. Thus the result that I want is:

```
let result = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "make_text": "Peugeot",
        "model_text": "307",
        "color_text": "Bleu",
        "category_text": "CT",
        "vin": "654321",
        "autralis_id": 0,
        "vehicle_id": 1,
        "zone": "T",
        "side": "B",
        "col": 2,
        "handled": 0,
        "uploaded": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "make_text": "Peugeot",
        "model_text": "307",
        "color_text": "Bleu",
        "category_text": "CT",
        "vin": "654321",
        "autralis_id": 0,
        "vehicle_id": 1,
        "zone": "A",
        "side": "E",
        "col": 1,
        "handled": 0,
        "uploaded": 0
    }
]
```

I tried to do it as follows:

```
let result = [];

vehicle_data.map(i => {
  vehicle_slot_data.map(j => {
    if (j.vehicle_id === i.id && j.handled === 0){
      result.push(Object.assign(i, j));
    }
  })
});
```

But with that I get the result with two same objects:

```
let result = [
   {
      autralis_id: 0,
      category_text: "CT",
      col: 1,
      color_text: "Bleu",
      handled: 0,
      id: 1,
      make_text: "Peugeot",
      model_text: "307",
      side: "E",
      uploaded: 0,
      vehicle_id: 1,
      vin: "654321",
      zone: "A"
   },
   {
      autralis_id: 0,
      category_text: "CT",
      col: 1,
      color_text: "Bleu",
      handled: 0,
      id: 1,
      make_text: "Peugeot",
      model_text: "307",
      side: "E",
      uploaded: 0,
      vehicle_id: 1,
      vin: "654321",
      zone: "A"
   }
]
```

[Here is the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/W4QfJ/4471/)

Any advice?

Comment: What should the output be if the first input array has an ID not in the second array? Or vice versa?

Comment: @nnnnnn It should not be added to the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nested loop seems more complicated than you need. Also, if you're using `.map()` but *not* returning a value then you're not using it correctly and should be using `.forEach()` for simple iteration.

Anyway, maybe something like this:

```js
let vehicle_data = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "make_text": "Peugeot",
    "model_text": "307",
    "color_text": "Bleu",
    "category_text": "CT",
    "vin": "654321",
    "autralis_id": 0
  }
]

let vehicle_slot_data = [
  {
    "vehicle_id": 1,
    "zone": "T",
    "side": "B",
    "col": 2,
    "handled": 0,
    "uploaded": 0
  },
  {
    "vehicle_id": 1,
    "zone": "A",
    "side": "E",
    "col": 1,
    "handled": 0,
    "uploaded": 0
  }
]

let result = vehicle_slot_data
  .map(v => Object.assign({}, v, vehicle_data.find(m => m.id === v.vehicle_id)))

console.log(result)
```

Note that you want to have `Object.assign()` start with a new empty object, and `.find()` returns `undefined` if there is no matching element.

EDIT: I just saw your comment about not including the items in the result if they're not matched (by ID) in both arrays). Expand the following for a way to do that:

```js
let vehicle_data = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "make_text": "Peugeot",
    "model_text": "307",
    "color_text": "Bleu",
    "category_text": "CT",
    "vin": "654321",
    "autralis_id": 0
  }
]

let vehicle_slot_data = [
  {
    "vehicle_id": 1,
    "zone": "T",
    "side": "B",
    "col": 2,
    "handled": 0,
    "uploaded": 0
  },
  {
    "vehicle_id": 2,
    "zone": "A",
    "side": "E",
    "col": 1,
    "handled": 0,
    "uploaded": 0
  }
]

let result = []
vehicle_slot_data.forEach(v => {
  var match = vehicle_data.find(m => m.id === v.vehicle_id)
  if (match)
    result.push(Object.assign({}, v, match))
})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an empty object as source object.

```
result.push(Object.assign({}, i, j));
//                        ^^
```

For better performance, i suggest to use [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and collect all vehicle data in a map and use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for slot data.

```js
let vehicle_data = [{ id: 1, make_text: "Peugeot", model_text: "307", color_text: "Bleu", category_text: "CT", vin: "654321", autralis_id: 0 }],
    vehicle_slot_data = [{ vehicle_id: 1, zone: "T", side: "B", col: 2, handled: 0, uploaded: 0 }, { vehicle_id: 1, zone: "A", side: "E", col: 1, handled: 0, uploaded: 0 }],
    vehicleMap = new Map(vehicle_data.map(v => [v.id, v])),
    result = vehicle_slot_data.map(v => Object.assign({}, vehicleMap.get(v.vehicle_id), v));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let vehicle_data = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "make_text": "Peugeot",
    "model_text": "307",
    "color_text": "Bleu",
    "category_text": "CT",
    "vin": "654321",
    "autralis_id": 0
  }
]

let vehicle_slot_data = [
  {
    "vehicle_id": 1,
    "zone": "T",
    "side": "B",
    "col": 2,
    "handled": 0,
    "uploaded": 0
  },
  {
    "vehicle_id": 1,
    "zone": "A",
    "side": "E",
    "col": 1,
    "handled": 0,
    "uploaded": 0
  }
]

let result = [];

vehicle_slot_data.map(i => {
      vehicle_data.map(j => {
        if (j.vehicle_id === i.id && i.handled === 0){
          result.push(Object.assign(i, j));
        }
      })
    });

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/1.2.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Just swap the maps:

```
  vehicle_slot_data.map(i => {
      vehicle_data.map(j => {
        if (j.vehicle_id === i.id && i.handled === 0){
          result.push(Object.assign(i, j));
        }
      })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the "concat"?

```js
function myFunction() {
    var hege = [{
    "id": 1,
    "make_text": "Peugeot",
    "model_text": "307",
    "color_text": "Bleu",
    "category_text": "CT",
    "vin": "654321",
    "autralis_id": 0
  }];
    var stale = [{
    "vehicle_id": 1,
    "zone": "T",
    "side": "B",
    "col": 2,
    "handled": 0,
    "uploaded": 0
  },
  {
    "vehicle_id": 1,
    "zone": "A",
    "side": "E",
    "col": 1,
    "handled": 0,
    "uploaded": 0
  }];
    var children = hege.concat(stale); 
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(children);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to join two arrays.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to merge `vehicle_slot_data[0]` with `vehicle_data[0]`,`vehicle_slot_data[1]` with `vehicle_data[0]` ,so I advice use jquery `extend` method ,or you can write a function to do the same job

```
var result=[
            $.extend({},vehicle_slot_data[0],vehicle_data[0]),
            $.extend({},vehicle_slot_data[1],vehicle_data[0])
           ]
```